# .net 4.5 mvc 5.2.3 on mono 4.8.0 view not created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, asp.net-mvc-5

.net 4.5 mvc 5.2.3 on mono 4.8.0 display error:

```
The view found at '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' was not created.
```

Exception stack trace:

```
  at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00061] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00080] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000b] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0004f] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `Web.config` file that is inside `/Views` folder. `system.web.webPages.razor` host parameter must match exactly with MVC version.

For example if you have MVC 5.2.3.0 then it should look like:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />.
```